# IE 11 is removing anchor tag from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

I have a situation where I add rich text is added in HTML. Chrome and Firefox is recognizing `<a>` tag but IE 11 is simply removing it from DOM. rest of text is displayed properly.

```
var t = $(".format-markdown").last().html().split("||");
$(".format-markdown").last().html('<span class="teaser">' + t[0] + '</span><span class="complete"><br/>' + t[1]  + '</span><span class="complete2"><br/>' + t[2]==undefined?"":t[2] + '</span><span class="l2support">See More</span><span class="l3support complete2">See More</span>');
```

I have tried removing `<p>` tag, but no good.

This is how Chrome reads it.

```
<p> For further details please refer to Slide 34 of this document
<a href="https://blahblah.com" target="_blank"><span>https://blahblah.com</span></a></p>
```

this is how IE 11 reads it

```
<p> For further details please refer to Slide 34 of this document
</p>
```

Please provide solution or any work around for this

Comment: Please give a reproducible example.